# What's wrong with my Checkprime.c program?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program that checks whether a given number is a prime number or not. However, my program just gives me the 2 time table, and I don't know why.

Here is my main class:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "defs.h"
#include "checkprime.c"


int Prime[MaxPrimes];  

int main()
{ 
  int UpperBound;
  int N;
  int *ba = &UpperBound;

  printf("enter upper bound\n");
  scanf("%d",ba);

  Prime[2] = 1;

  for (N = 3; N <= *ba; N+= 2)
  {
    CheckPrime(N);
    if (Prime[N]== 1) printf("%d is a prime\n",N);
  }
}
```

Here is my checkprime.c

```
#include "defs.h"
#include "externs.h"


int CheckPrime(int K)
{

  int J;


  J = 2;

  while (1)  
  {
    if (Prime[J] == 1)
    {
      if (K % J == 0)  
      {
         Prime[K] = 0;
         return 0;
      }
      J++; 
    } 
    break;
  }   

  Prime[K] = 1; 
}
```

Comment: There is an unconditional `break` inside the `while(1)` loop. So it only ever iterates once.

Comment: Do you understand what you are doing in this line `scanf("%d",ba);` ?

Comment: @noob isn't `ba` already a pointer?

Comment: If I remove the break it says: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)
"

Comment: That is because you don't check the array bounds. How about `while(J < MaxPrimes)`

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Yes sir it is. But my questions is why use pointer here ? For simple `UpperBound` which is an integer.

Comment: "Here is my main class:" - Which class? Is that supposed to be C++? Well, there is no class and C does not support classes at all.

Comment: I've had Java before, so I didn't know what to call it. I thought it was called the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in `CheckPrime` with the loop exit conditions.  Use the following instead:

```
int CheckPrime(int K)
{
    int J;

    for (J=2; J*J <= K; J++) {
        if (Prime[J] == 1) {
            if (K % J == 0) {
                Prime[K] = 0;
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    Prime[K] = 1;
    return 1;
}
```

The rest of it should work with this change.

Comment: Thanks! Can't I keep `While(1)` and fix something else?

Comment: Sure, if you want to undo the `for` loop and instead use a `while` loop it's easy enough.  I can't imagine why you'd want to fight the language like that, but it's simple enough.  If I were grading a C assignment, I'd take off points for using a `while` loop when a `for` loop is the natural choice.

Comment: But I didn't understand what the problem was with my while loop. What was it? :)

Comment: Oh, well there were a few problems:  (1) There was an unconditional `break` at the bottom of the loop, so it wasn't a loop at all (2) With the `break` removed, it was now an infinite loop in the case of primes (fixed by adding the `J*J <= K` condition) (3) J was only being incremented if it indexed a prime, rather than every time through the loop, so it would get stuck on the first composite factor (4) There was a missing `return 1` in the case where `K` was prime (this wasn't used in your example, but it didn't make sense since it's an `int` function that returns `0` for composites).